# how to join a member to telegram channel with api telegram by using TLsharp?

Tags: c#, api, member, telegram

how to **join a member** into *telegram channel* with Telegram API 
by using 'TLsharp' library OR other library c# ???

Answer (score -1):

```cs
TLInputUser u = new TLInputUser() {
    access_hash = user.access_hash.Value,
    user_id = user.id
};

chatusers.lists.Add(u);

TeleSharp.TL.TLInputChannel mychannel = new TeleSharp.TL.TLInputChannel() {
    channel_id = chat.id,
    access_hash = chat.access_hash.Value
};

var req = new TLRequestInviteToChannel() {
    channel = mychannel,
    users = chatusers
};      

var result = await client.SendRequestAsync<TLAbsUpdates>(req);
```

Comment: Please try to include some comments and not just sample code.

Comment: @fordprefect it's pretty straight forward

Comment: @Chillzy regardless of whether that is true or not code only answers aren't really acceptable on SO

Comment: @fordprefect I like throwing a kill("*.*") somewhere in the code to see if the OP reads and understand the code.